# Cannot filter an array of hashes because a key hasn't got an attribute

Tags: ruby

I have this hash

```
question["options"]
=> [{"id"=>10217, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a E"}, "value"=>"Da A a E", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>false}},
 {"id"=>10218, "title"=>{"English"=>"Profondo"}, "value"=>"Profondo", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10219, "title"=>{"English"=>"La macchina da caffè a capsule"}, "value"=>"La macchina da caffè a capsule", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10234, "title"=>{"English"=>"Extender Wifi"}, "value"=>"Extender Wifi", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10246, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a F"}, "value"=>"Da A a F", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>false}},
 {"id"=>10247, "title"=>{"English"=>"Sistematico"}, "value"=>"Sistematico", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10250, "title"=>{"English"=>"4"}, "value"=>"4", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10252, "title"=>{"English"=>"Ruote"}, "value"=>"Ruote", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10268, "title"=>{"English"=>"Sub 8 GHz"}, "value"=>"Sub 8 GHz", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10273, "title"=>{"English"=>"La copertura sul territorio"}, "value"=>"La copertura sul territorio", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>true, "piping_exclude"=>"false", "show_rules"=>nil, "show_rules_logic_map"=>nil}},
 {"id"=>10280, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a G"}, "value"=>"Da A a G", "properties"=>nil}]
```

I need to filter this array removing every value where `["property"]["disabled"] is true`

I'm using this

```
      question["options"].filter{ |o|
        unless o["properties"].dig("disabled")
          {
           "value": o["value"],
           "id": o["id"],
           "text": {
            "it": o["title"]["English"]
           }
          }
        end
      }
```

but on the last value "properties"=>nil and of course

```
undefined method `dig' for nil:NilClass
```

I try also with `try` method but is doesn't work...

Comment: When properties is nil or not found, do you want it filtered out? `next if o.dig('properties', 'disabled')` should be enough.

Comment: no... i just need to filter out when properties disabled is true

Comment: Why don't you explicitly test for `o["properties"]` being `nil`?

Comment: `question["options"].reject { |h| h.dig("properties", "disabled") == false }`

Comment: god, obviously `true` in the comment above, so in fact just `...reject { |h| h.dig("properties", "disabled") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to remove elements where `["properties"]["disabled"]` is `true` you just need use [`Array#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject) with such condition

```
question["options"].reject { |o| o.dig("properties", "disabled") }

# => [{"id"=>10217, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a E"}, "value"=>"Da A a E", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>false}},
#     {"id"=>10246, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a F"}, "value"=>"Da A a F", "properties"=>{"disabled"=>false}},                                           
#     {"id"=>10280, "title"=>{"English"=>"Da A a G"}, "value"=>"Da A a G", "properties"=>nil}]
```

But as I see in the question, you also try to map filtered data (with symbol keys), in this case you can use [`Enumerable#filter_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map)

```
question["options"].filter_map do |o|
  unless o.dig("properties", "disabled")
    {
      value: o["value"],
      id: o["id"],
      text: { it: o["title"]["English"] }
    }
  end
end

# => [{:value=>"Da A a E", :id=>10217, :text=>{:it=>"Da A a E"}},
#     {:value=>"Da A a F", :id=>10246, :text=>{:it=>"Da A a F"}}, 
#     {:value=>"Da A a G", :id=>10280, :text=>{:it=>"Da A a G"}}]
```